# JQueryUI Dialog Modal Function not working

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I've tried to make the dialog modal option work for quite a while now, but still haven't figured out what went wrong and why it isn't working for me.

Tried looking at other posts on stackoverflow and the dialog widget page on the official jQueryUI website, but i still can't solve it.

Here are my codes:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="JQueryUI-1.12.1/jquery- 
ui.css"
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="JQueryUI-1.12.1/jquery- 
ui.structure.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="JQueryUI-1.12.1/jquery- 
ui.theme.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="messageBox" title="Message">
<p> Thank you for visiting our website </p>
</div>

</div>


<script src="JQuery-3.3.1-Library.js"></script>
<script src="JQueryUI-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$("document").ready(function(){

$("#messageBox").dialog({show: {effect: "bounce", duration:1500}})
        .dialog({hide: {effect: "explode", duration:1500}})
        .dialog({closeOnEscape: false})
        .dialog({modal:true});

</script>
</body>
```

Hoping that someone would help me.

Comment: Can you **explain** what is not working with that code? Without any explanation, we cannot help

Comment: i used ( modal: true ) but i still can click on the contents of the webpage behind the messageBox

Comment: Does the code work on ur computer?

Answer (score -1):

I recommend cdn instead of local files (this isn't fix your problem, but possibly come with some benefits, read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/92083/local-files-vs-cdn) for more info, and you missed one "});"

I tested this code and it worked normally, check if you have any errors on your chrome console and tell us if you have

```
<body>
       <div id="container">
           <div id="messageBox" title="Message">
                <p> Thank you for visiting our website </p>
           </div>
       </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {

        $("#messageBox").dialog({
                show: {
                    effect: "bounce",
                    duration: 1500
                }
            })
            .dialog({
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1500
                }
            })
            .dialog({
                closeOnEscape: false
            })
            .dialog({
                modal: true
            });
    }); // you missed this
</script>
```

Comment: i placed the }); but it still didnt work, but thanks for the point out. I've also tried copying ur code onto my notepad(using the cdn method) but i still can't make the modal property work. Is it because of my computer?

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why should loading the code using a CDN help if some functions are not working?

Comment: i'd also like to know, thx.
Also i'd like to know if
1) others are able to have the code above works properly on their computer, specifically the ({modal:true}); function. 
2) you are using the newest jqueryUI version.
Because i'd like to know if the error is caused by the computer or does the latest version of jqueryUI no longer support this method (Although it is still one of the methods displayed on their website)